# How to count result

Tags: php, html, css, sql, count

I don't know much about  PHP and I came on a problem, how to be able to display the number of results.
 Example: 'There are 200 results'.
Thank you in advance.

Attached is my code

```
try
{
 $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdf", "root", "");
 $bdd ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  die("Une érreur a été trouvé : " . $e->getMessage());
}
$bdd->query("SET NAMES UTF8");

if (isset($_GET["s"]) AND $_GET["s"] == "Rechercher")

{
 $_GET["terme"] = htmlspecialchars($_GET["terme"]); //pour sécuriser le formulaire contre les intrusions html
 $terme = $_GET["terme"];
 $terme = trim($terme); //pour supprimer les espaces dans la requête de l'internaute
 $terme = strip_tags($terme); //pour supprimer les balises html dans la requête

 if (isset($terme))
 {
  $terme = strtolower($terme);
  $select_terme = $bdd->prepare("SELECT titre, description, lien, lien_image FROM bdr WHERE titre LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?");
  $select_terme->execute(array("%".$terme."%", "%".$terme."%"));

 }
 else
 {
  $message = "Vous devez entrer votre requete dans la barre de recherche";
 }
}

 while($terme_trouve = $select_terme->fetch())
  {
   ...
  }

  $select_terme->closeCursor();



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few approaches:

 1. use `$counter` and increase it

```
$counter=0;
while($terme_trouve = $select_terme->fetch())
  {
   ...
   $counter++;
  }
echo "cnt=".$counter;
```

2. Use a second sql and get count directly

```
$select_terme = $bdd->prepare("SELECT count(1) as cnt FROM bdr WHERE titre LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?");
```

3. use a build in function with initial sql to count

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result_query);
```

or depend how connection is obtained (above case)

```
$rowcount = $select_terme->rowCount();
```

or

```
$rowcount = $select_terme->fetchColumn(); 
(count on select)
```